# swift link how all searchbar results to same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, searchbar

I have a SearchViewController. The image for the SearchViewController is:- 
 [image]

and the code for the SearchViewController is:-

```swift
import UIKit  
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,      UISearchBarDelegate    {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
   let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
               "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
               "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
               "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
               "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]


   var filteredData: [String]!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableView.dataSource = self
       searchBar.delegate = self
       filteredData = data
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
       cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
       return cell
   }  

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return filteredData.count
   }
   // This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       let  searchT =  searchText.count < 2 // will give sulggestion when at least 2 chrs in box
       filteredData = searchT ? data : data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
           // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
           return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
       }
       func updateSearchResults(for searchBar: UISearchBar) {
           view.isHidden = true
       }
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

The "SearchViewController" works fine, no problem with that. Now,  I  have tried to link "SearchViewController" to another ViewController, say "AllSegueViewController", which is on the right of the "SearchViewController", through a segue. The name of the Segue is  "PickUpSegueFromRight"(see the first image above and code below). The segue normally works fine, i.e swipes right, but not in this case.

```swift
import UIKit

class PickUpSegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: +src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut],
                       animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

When I run "SearchViewController" on the Simulator, it works fine, as shown in image below:- 
    [image]

My problem:- My first and main problem is that what should I add in "SearchViewController" and/or "PickUpSegueFromRight" and/or  "AllSegueViewController" so that when I click on any of the search results, eg. "Chicago, IL"(see simulator image above), it should go to the "AllSegueViewController" ?  Secondly, I want to add/append the search results in the "AllSegueViewController". My second and small problem is that I also want to add arrow images to all search result rows, eg. "Chicago, IL" etc., so  that it should suggest the user that clicking on it should swipe right to "AllSegueViewController".

Answer (score 1):

1. No need to use PickUpSegueFromRight class, easier way is click the segue and set kind of segue in attribute inspector to present or push
2. You can custom your UITableViewCell or use "disclosure indicator" in UITableviewcell by default

Comment: where to use it ? I don't want to use navigationController

Comment: 1. The first part of your answer is wrong, maybe because you missed out a point. I need to swipe right. 2. second part of your answer helped me though you should have specified i.e the quickest way is - " Click on "Tablecell", go to its attributes inspector and set its Accessory to "Disclosure indicator. It adds arrow right image to the TableCell."